# In which version HBase integrate a spark API?

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I read the documentation of spark and hbase :

http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#spark

I can see that the last stable version of HBase is [1.1.2](http://mirrors.ircam.fr/pub/apache/hbase/stable/), but I also see that apidocs is on version [2.0.0-SNAPSHOT](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/index.html) and that the [apidoc of spark](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/spark/package-summary.html) is empty.

I am confused, why the apidocs and HBase version don't match?

My goal is to use Spark and HBase (bulkGet, bulkPut..etc). How do I know in which HBase version those functions have been implemented?

If someone have complementary documentation on this, it will be awesome.

I am on hbase-0.98.13-hadoop1.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Seems like the are still doing the development , so the API docs are empty.

Comment: As far as I can see, `spark 1.6` is using  `hbase 0.98.7` .

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Spark doesn't come with HBase API as it has for the hive, you have manually put HBase jars in spark's classpath in spark-default.conf file.

see below link it has complete information about how to connect to HBase:

http://www.abcn.net/2014/07/lighting-spark-with-hbase-full-edition.html

Answer (score 0):

Below is the main JIRA ticket for Spark integration into HBase, the target version is **2.0.0** which still under development, need waiting for the release, or build a version from source code by your own

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-13992

Within the ticket, there are several links for documentation.

If you just want to access HBase from Spark RDD, you can consider it as normal Hadoop datasource, based on HBase specific TableInputFormat and TableOutputFormat